# Feedback to improve this question

Tags: discussion, support

I asked a [question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/86935/does-1-timothy-517-apply-exclusively-to-pastors-of-local-churches) of exegesis and interpretation on a passage in 1 Timothy, but it was closed for being "opinion-based". I wanted to know if it was correct to interpret that all pastors should be worthy of double honor, or this verse deals only with the local church. For this, I am asking for suggestions and feedback for improvements to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I see you tagged with with [protestantism](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protestantism) could you figure out a way to add that to the title and body of your question.  "According to Protestantism" is kind of vague.  But you could ask how most Protestant churches apply (or if).

Basically, and I know this seems odd, but tagging is for classification, not for scoping.

Comment: However even then, individual verses are interpreted in multiple ways by Protestants. The problem is the question seeks The One True Answer, when that just can't be given.